# tranfer of resultset from jsp to html page

Tags: html, jsp

I have created the html page,on which login is provided i had search it on mysql using .jsp file, and got resultset. From that resultset i want to send login id to another page through jsp (and that html page will be loaded and will have that login id.)

Comment: Do you understand what you're doing good enough? You'd better rephrase the question so that we could understand your point and you should definitely spice it up with your code attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do

```
<%
    while (rs.next()) {
%>

  //Create you html here

    <div>
         <%=rs.getString(1)%>  
   </div>


  //Html ends here

<%
    }
%>
```

And refer this also  [How do I make a Java ResultSet available in my jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384189/how-do-i-make-a-java-resultset-available-in-my-jsp) for proper MVC structure.